# Cannot run JavaFx project on browser

Tags: java, javafx, java-web-start

I did config and deploy it step by step like this tutorial but when I run the html file in browser it show me something like that and ask me to install java8 but I had it already. This is the screenshoot when I run it in Chrome and FireFox
[image: Running in Chrome]

[image: Running in FireFox]

Could anyone help me about it. I am a newbie of JavaFx :)

Comment: Did you check your `.jnlp` file? The error message says "the following required field is missing: **main-class**"

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did add janela.jar to my project but it still not work :(

Comment: @AndreasFester Yes, that is my error but could you tell me what I should check in the .jnlp file. I don't know what I miss in this file.

Comment: *"I did add janela.jar to my project but it still not work :("* Note that `check the JNLP using JaNeLA` is **not** equal to `add JaNeLA Jar to your project`.  If you don't understand a suggestion, the best thing to do is ask.  But please be specific about what you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you, so I don't understand what is janela.jar use for? Is it an enviroment help us run JavaFx project in browser.

Comment: Besides, could anyone tell me what do "codebase" element use for, I write path to my jnlp file but it's not success ("file://")

Comment: Codebase define your path where web start can find your JAR files. If you define your dependencies like this: `<jar href="myfile.jar"/>` web start will try to download `codebase/myfile.jar`. Read [JNLP File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) for more information.